# Run reverse Django migration on Heroku after release failure

Tags: django, heroku, django-migrations

I have a running Django application on Heroku with migrations auto-run on release. While in most times this works fine sometimes there is a problem when:

- There are more than one migration in given release (they can be in different apps)
- Some migration will fail, but not the first one

In this case `manage.py migrate` will fail so Heroku will not finish the release and will not deploy the new code. This means that code is in the old version and the database is in the state "somewhere between old and new".

Is there a simple way to autorun Django run reversed migrations in case of the failure of the release command on Heroku?

Transactions won't help here as there might be more than one migration (multiple apps) and Django run each migration in seperate transaction.

Comment: Have you looked at https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/release-phase#design-considerations?
As of what I can read, it doesn't look like there is such an option to "revert back" migrations.

Comment: I dont believe in "there is no way to do this", at worst I could write my own migrate command, but I am looking for some simpler way.

Comment: Sorry, I was just taking the first relevant result from a quick google search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I couldn't find any existing solutions I am posting a gist I have written to solve this.

https://gist.github.com/pax0r/0591855e73b9892c28d3e3cdd15f4985

The code stores the state of migrations before running the migration and in case of any exception reverts back to this state. It also checks if all migrations are reversible during the `migrate` step.

It's not yet well tested, but I will work forward to create a library from it for easier use by others.